# Java JDBC swing login form error

Tags: java, mysql, swing, jdbc

I am currently working on a simple JDBC project and I am stuck at the login form

```
 private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    try
{
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/company","root","redhat");
    stmt=con.createStatement(); 
    String nm=jTextField1.getText();
    char[] pass=jPasswordField1.getPassword();
    String pw=Arrays.toString(pass);
    String sql="select * from login where uname='"+nm+"' and pass='"+pw+"'";
    rs=stmt.executeQuery(sql);
    if(rs.next())
     {
      new MainPage().setVisible(true);
      this.setVisible(false);
     }
    else
     {
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Wrong User name or password");
      jTextField1.setText("");
      jPasswordField1.setText("");

     }
}
catch(Exception e)
{
  System.out.println(e);
}
}              `
```

When this button is clicked a new page that I have created is to be shown ,but it shows "Wrong User name or password" message dialog.
What are my mistakes?
My database is in mysql.

Comment: try to print both values `nm+" and "+pw` and you will see the difference

Comment: build up your string using String.format

Comment: Your connection string is missing the port number though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Arrays.ToString Returns a string representation of the contents of the specified array. The string representation consists of a list of the array's elements.

In your case Instead of

```
String pw = Arrays.toString(pass);
```

You should be using to get the password in String representation.

```
String pw = String.copyValueOf(pass);
```

Answer (score 3):

*Error 1:* [`Arrays.toString(char[])`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString-char:A-) will return an array representation, e.g. if the password in `jPasswordField1` is `password`, the result is this string: `[p, a, s, s, w, o, r, d]`

*Fix 1:* Use [`new String(char[])`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#String-char:A-) instead.

---

*Error 2:* Using string concatenation to build a SQL statement. This will make your code susceptible to [SQL Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks, where hackers can **steal your data and delete your tables**.

*Fix 2:* Use a [`PreparedStatement`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html).

---

*Error 3:* Not releasing resources. This will lead to memory leaks.

*Fix 3:* Use [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html).

---

*Result:*

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    try {
        boolean loginOk;
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        try (Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/company","root","redhat")) {
            String sql = "select * from login where uname=? and pass=?";
            try (PreparedStatement stmt = con.prepareStatement(sql)) {
                stmt.setString(1, jTextField1.getText());
                stmt.setString(2, new String(jPasswordField1.getPassword()));
                try (ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql)) {
                    loginOk = rs.next();
                }
            }
        }
        if (loginOk) {
            new MainPage().setVisible(true);
            this.setVisible(false);
        } else {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Wrong User name or password");
            jTextField1.setText("");
            jPasswordField1.setText("");
        }
    } catch(Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That would seem to indicate that your query returns an empty result set.  What happens if you run it against the DB directly?

Also, `Arrays.toString(...)` will give you a String representation of the array.  You probably want the contents of the array in a String - there's a difference.  Try using `new String(pass)` instead.

Answer (score 0):

I think "Wrong User name or password" means rs is null or rs'size is 0.
You should check the name and password.